# Dozens (and dozens) of applications with no name or icon in Dash

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, unity-dash

I upgraded from 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS. I have dozens (and dozens) of applications with no name or icon in Dash.

Where are these coming from? How can I clean them up?

[image: Apps with no name]

Edit: Thanks for the suggestions. It turns out these were all coming from:

```
~/.local/share/applications/menu-xdg
```

I "deleted" this folder and everything is fine now.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was coming from files in:

```
~/.local/share/applications/menu-xdg
```

I made a backup of "menu-xdg" then deleted it. Everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

It was beacuse the update, go to the software center and install "alacarte", then on dash open main menu
Quit all the missing apps

Comment: I have this app. Cheers. It turns out all it does is write files to `~/.local/share/applications` It was easier for me to just work with the text files in that dir. Thanks for the help.